# Does callback copy jnienv, jinstance inside a JNI function?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

The lambda that I pass to builder is populated into `className` object, and called at regular intervals (every hour) of time to refresh the other members. It gets called the first time successfully. I'm not sure if the lambda retains `env`, `instance` to legally call the reverse JNI function?

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_company_app_ClassName_JniInit(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance){
  int data = 0;
  auto builder = new Builder(data,
        [env, instance]() -> std::string {
            std::string stringObj = populateData(env, instance); // This function makes a reverse JNI call to get data from a java function in the class
            return stringObj;
        }
    );

  std::shared_ptr<className> = builder->build(); 

  return 1;
}
```

I seem to be getting a SIGNAL 11 error, SIGSEGV. Is this kind of segmentation fault catchable in any way, so the app doesn't crash?

`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x228 in tid 21785 (ClassName), pid 21573 (.company.app)`

It seems to be crashing at this line inside `populateData`-

`jstring data = (jstring)(env)->CallObjectMethod(instance, javaFunctionName);`

Is there a way to check if this function will fail before calling it? I checked if `env` (`JNIEnv*` argument in `populateData`) is `NULL`, but its not, and has a valid address along with `instance` (`jinstance` argument in `populateData`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question, I have found a slightly different kind of hack.

Don't copy the `JNIEnv`, and `object` or create references to them. They get deleted as soon as your JNI function goes out of scope. I'm not sure why copying doesn't work (if someone could answer this, that would be great). Alternatively, I've used `JavaVM*` to maintain a local reference of the jvm, you can do this in your `JNI_OnLoad`.

Use the function below, and it would work fine.

```
JavaVM* jvm; // Initialise this in OnLoad

JNIEnv *getJNIEnv()
   {
        JNIEnv *env = nullptr;
        jint ret = jvm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6);
        if (ret == JNI_EDETACHED || !env)
        {
            env = nullptr;
        }
        return env;
   }
```

If you need the class instance, you'll need to initialise it via `JNIEnv`, but I use a static method for my class, so I just fetched the class using `env->FindClass` and then you can do `env->GetStaticMethodID` along with `env->CallStaticObjectMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have problems with jobject instance if this function does something asynchronously.  The reason is that before this function is started, Java marks the object as having an extra reference.  It removes that when it returns.  So after it returns, the object can be cleaned up by the garbage collector if there's no other instances in the Java code.

This can be fixed by calling  `NewGlobalRef(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)` before starting the async function on the main thread, and calling `DeleteGlobalRef` at the end of the callback when jobject is no longer needed.